# Discrete Math: Functions and Set Questions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

**1) Consider the function: $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (Real to Real Number), where $f(x)=2+x^2$, what would be all of the preimages of $3$?**

1) $11$

2) $11$, $-11$

3) $1$, $-1$

4) $1$

**2) Let $D = \{a,b,c\}$ and let $E = \{2,4\}$, we will define the function $f$ as 
$f: D \to E$ with the following facts.**

$f(a)=2$

$f(b)=2$

$f(c)=4$

*Based on this information, what is accurate regarding the function of $f$?*

1) $f$ is a "bijection"

2) $f$ is considered to be "one-to-one"

3) $f$ is "onto" and "one-to-one"

4) $f$ is "onto"

Comment: Can you show the work you've done so far on the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image $f(X) = \{ f(x) : x \in X \}$. So to find the preimage of $3$, you want $\{ x : f(x) = 3 \}$. So set $3 = 2 + x^{2}$. You should be able to take it from here.

For part (ii), a one-to-one function is a function such that $f(a) = f(b) \implies a = b$. Here, you have $f(a) = f(b)$, but $a \neq b$. An onto function is one such that $\forall{y} \in E$, $\exists{x} \in D$ such that $f(x) = y$. In other words, does every element in $E$ get mapped to? Clearly, yes.

A bijection is a one-to-one and onto function.

Comment: So the answer to part 2 will be number 4 then right?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: I think I get this! So one more question, and I'm gonna mark yours as right. Suppose I have 2 functions f and g that both are mapped Real to Real like in problem #1. f(x)=x^2 and g(x)=3x, what would (f∘g)(2) this be equal to? I'm not familiar with what the symbol "∘" means?

Comment: The symbol is a hollow circle, it's hard to see on stack exchange.

Comment: This is functional composition. It means $f(g(2))$.

Comment: Ah so it would be 12 then

Comment: Wait actually I think you might have it backwards? I think (f∘g)2 would be f(g(2)) based on wikipedia's definition

Comment: Anyhow thanks for all the help, I really appreciate it! :)